# SQL one to many relationship, but many to one table relationship

Tags: mysql, sql, database, foreign-keys

I have 5 tables that can contain a phone field, but I want to have the option for multiple phone numbers for each table.

Instead of creating 5 sub tables, it makes more sense to create one, and link it to the other 5 "parent" tables. But now I am thinking of how to link that table to the other 5.

My first thought was to filter on 2 subjects. A field that stores the name of the linked table, and a generic foreign key that contains the key from one of the five tables. I'm still leaning this way.

Next is the idea of putting 5 foreign keys into the table, and allowing them to be null. I dislike both the idea of 4 null fields. Not to mention I have the same issue with another table that would link to 11 other tables in a similar manner.

The third is a linking or junction table, again (I believe,) with 5 nullable foreign keys, but this doesn't seem to do anything more then option 2 with a little more complexity.

4th option, I'm using an auto-increment field for the primary key for most of my tables. I could switch to a UUID or GUID for these tables. I'm already set up to use UUID as primary for security reasons, but was using auto-increment for most tables for performance.

A 5th option is something I ran into where an auto-increment field was combined with a table name to create a new character field. (Only during creation of the table, so technically isn't a calculated field.) But again don't see the benefit of this beyond the first option.

Is one of these the best way to go, or is there another option I either missed, or do not understand?

Comment: Well, the most important thing is that you totally avoided the thought of putting comma separated values in the tables. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to assign **the same phone number** to three records (form your 5 tables) do you want add three records with the same phone number to your "phone_numbers" table?

It's a optimization issue, so there is no "good way" in SQL-semantics sense.

In my opinion the easiest to use in development is the first way: *table_name* and *id* in this table, but don't use varchar. Use enum or "table_name_id" TINYINT (ref to second table with names).

Answer (score 0):

Don't make it so complex while you can do this easily 
You can do this using single table. I am giving you an Example below :

UserId | PhoneNo | PhoneType | ParentId

where UserId : is Id of user
Phone no is raw phone/ mobile number
PhoneType :  phone/ mobile number
Parent ID : is the main key point here by default it is 0  to treat it as a separate entry other wise same tabl's UserID to identify it as a child phone number..think it as a tree relation ship..
It's a simple and efficient way to do that as far as I know.